# Not seeing my wsdl.xml in /api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

Tags: magento-1, api, soap-api-v2, wsdl

**EDIT: SOLVED**

When I go to /api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 on my site I am not seeing what I have added in my module wsdl.xml file.

Under `<xsd:complexType name="salesOrderItemEntity">` my element that I added is not being displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <complexType name="salesOrderItemEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="belongs_to_sku" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

Am I misunderstanding how it works and everything is as it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add wsi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
            <xsd:complexType name="salesOrderItemEntity">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="belongs_to_sku" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```